# Why don't any sites use OAuth?

Tags: authentication, cookies, oauth, openid-connect

As I understand oauth is the natural evolution of authentication protocols

I understand in a general way that evolution is as follows:

1. basic authentication
2. cookies
3. tokens, at this point you want to separate the front from the back.
4. oauth,openid connect ... centralized way of handling authentication and having authorization and authentication servers.

But I have entered to inspect the requests of the sites that I use daily, such as social networks, stackoverflow, google apps... and to my surprise I didn't find any trace of tokens or oauth redirects.

Why do big sites use cookies for authentication? even when they are a single page app.
Are there any security features that make cookies more secure than tokens?

do you know any big site that uses oauth to maintain the session and not only for the login with social networks?

Answer (score 0):

The Oauth protocol does keep a session for the end user with the Oauth authentication server.

The application is delegating authentication to the Oauth server. The session for the application is managed by the access token that is returned. When the access token expires the session with the application must be renewed.

Depending on the access pattern, this can take different forms. Oauth was not designed to be a session management protocol and as a result using it for that can lead to security vulnerabilities.

Openid-connect is an implementation of Oauth that does support session managment[Openid Connect Session Management](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#rnc:%7E:text=%C2%A0TOC-,2.%C2%A0%20Creating%20and%20Updating%20Sessions,-In%20OpenID%20Connect) When Oauth or OpenId connect is used, the seamless login experience we enjoy, where we do not have to login every time our access token expires is due to the backchannel request using the refresh token. This is only secure in a backchannel request, which is why you do not see it in your browser inspection. Browsers are untrusted space, if the refresh token was sent through a front channel request, it would not be secure at all.

So some implementations do in fact manage the session